# Does there exist a Noetherian ring of finite injective dimension but higher Krull dimension?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

**Definition**: a (not necessarily commutative) left and right Noetherian ring $R$ is said to be Auslander-Gorenstein if

(i) $R$ has finite left and right injective dimension (in which case it turns out they are equal)

(ii) For any f.g. $R$-module $M$ and submodule $N$ of $Ext^j(M, R)$, $Ext^i(N, R) = 0$ whenever $i < j$

There are two results which relate this to Krull dimension:

1. If $R$ is commutative Noetherian and has finite injective dimension $n$ then (a) it is Auslander-Gorenstein and (b) $Kdim(R) = n$. **[[1](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.152.1137%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=GixoUc6ECOHJ0QWiyIDYAQ&usg=AFQjCNGBPOmxQpTiwNWHU7_VO913L1YCEw&sig2=7eWvtMWlSkz8tXCXWIsw-g&bvm=bv.45175338,d.d2k&cad=rja)]**
2. If $R$ is Auslander-Gorenstein of injective dimension $n$ then $Kdim(R) \leq n$. **[[2](https://www.math.washington.edu/~smith/Research/asz6.pdf)]**

So the question is: does there exist a (left and right) Noetherian ring of finite injective dimension $n$ with $Kdim(R) > n$? That is, does the second result actually require $R$ to be Auslander-Gorenstein, or did it only need the injective-dimension-finite part?

Obviously, those two results mean that such an $R$ cannot be commutative or Auslander-Gorenstein. Unfortunately, the commonly quoted example of a Noetherian ring which is not Auslander-Gorenstein - $\left( \begin{array}{cc}
k & V \\
0 & k \end{array} \right)$ for $V$ a $k$-vector space of dimension at least 2 - is Artinian, so doesn't help.

**[[1](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.152.1137%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=GixoUc6ECOHJ0QWiyIDYAQ&usg=AFQjCNGBPOmxQpTiwNWHU7_VO913L1YCEw&sig2=7eWvtMWlSkz8tXCXWIsw-g&bvm=bv.45175338,d.d2k&cad=rja)]**: Hyman Bass. On the ubiquity of Gorenstein rings, 1963.

**[[2](https://www.math.washington.edu/~smith/Research/asz6.pdf)]**: K. Ajitabh, S. P. Smith, and J. J Zhang. Auslander-Gorenstein rings, 1998.

Comment: It seems that your first result says that the answer is no.

Comment: Fernando's right, you must have mis-typed something. Are you actually trying to ask about a ring $R$ which is Auslander-Gorenstein and has Krull dimension not equal to injective dimension (hence $R$ cannot be Noetherian)?

Comment: Oh, I misread this. The condition you're trying to weaken is commutativity. But then do you have to distinguish between right injective dimension and left injective dimension?

Comment: @David, there's no nice Krull dimension for noncommutative rings.

Comment: @David - fortunately, no, there's a result of Zaks which says that if right and left injective dimension are finite then they're equal.

@Fernando - the definition of Krull dimension for non-commutative rings may not be nice, but it certainly exists and is studied!

@all - sorry for being unclear about definitions and non-commutativity. I've added some more background that hopefully makes things clearer.

